# OnAuthorization function containing user's defined object?

Tags: c#, authorization

I have a code from GitHub where the user defined his own `AuthorizeAttribute` with the following function:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var account = (Account)context.HttpContext.Items["Account"];
        if (account == null || (_roles.Any() && !_roles.Contains(account.Role)))
        {
            // not logged in or role not authorized
            context.Result = new JsonResult(new { message = "Unauthorized" }) { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized };
        }
    }
```

I don't understand why  `context.HttpContext.Items` would contain an `Account` object - where is it comming from?

Comment: Somewhere somebody is allocating the value, for example `context.HttpContext.Items["Account"] = myObject`

Comment: You were absolutely right - I found the place. Thank you.